# Trying to store an object in localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm trying to save some data to localStorage but for some reason all I get is an empty array.

```
var saveData = JSON.parse(localStorage.saveData || null) || {};

function saveGame() {
  saveData.buildings = "buildings";
  saveData.resources = resources;
  saveData.time = new Date();

  localStorage.saveData = JSON.stringify(saveData);
}
```

`JSON.stringify(saveData)` returns `[]` and 
`SaveData` returns something weird when I put it on watch:

```
Array[0]
- buildings: "buildings"
- length: 0
- resources: Object
- time: <time>
- __proto__: Array[0]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems to be working just fine for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/N9L2h/1/

Comment: Out of curiosity, what browser are you using?

Comment: Are you sure there is no code elsewhere that is setting saveData to an array?

Comment: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N9L2h/3/) --> This is how it breaks, I suspect the resources object breaks it? I had to clear my cache to see it break.

Comment: Nevermind, I can't seem to break it on JsFiddle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem:
`var saveData = JSON.parse(localStorage.saveData || null) || {};`

Used to be:
`var saveData = JSON.parse(localStorage.saveData || null) || [];`

`saveData` remained cached as an empty array breaking the code.